# Set contents to string

Tags: python, string, set

Searching for an answer I found the following code in a related question.

```
>>> v=set(['letters'])
>>> v
{'letters'}
>>> str(v)
"{'letters'}"
```

The result of the below doesn't go as specific as I want it.  Is there a neat way to just get the result `'letters'`?

Comment: What is `v`? What are you trying to achieve EXACTLY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over all items in the set:

```
for item in v:
    print v
```

Answer (score 2):

ummm lots of ways one way

```
print str(v)[1:-1]
```

but its not very clear what you whant to actually do

another way that answers your question is

```
print "'letters'"
```

another way is

```
print repr("letters")
print repr(v.pop())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the first item in a set this way:

```
>>> v = set(['letters'])
>>> next(iter(v))
'letters'
```

But, remember, sets are unordered collections.